# Fastest way to remove the null elements in a list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

Is there a quick way of removing the 
null elements from a linked list?

The only way i know is to iterate on the 
elements and remove the null ones.

I don't see how multithreading would help-- linked list doesn't have direct access to its members.

////////////////////////////////

EDIT: One I could think of is putting the elements into a set then back to the list again. This wouldn't retain the order, However would work every otherwise(?)

Comment: Well, multithreading *could* help -- two threads working their way towards the middle from either end. Not too sure how this would be accomplished though.

Comment: I don't know of one, nor can I think of how one would work. Linked lists are meant for sequential access, not random, so I believe you'll just have to loop through all items.

Comment: Technically, the only way to traverse or edit a linked list is by iteration. That is the definition of a linked list. Also, if you had null elements in a linked list, you would technically have a broken list.

Comment: @Humdinger Why would `null` elements in a linked list break it? `null` elements are perfectly legal in Java's implementation. Does that mean that Java's implementation is broken?

Comment: @user3582094 This is a little of an edge case, where multithread only helps up to 2 threads.

Comment: @user3580294 It depends if the OBJECT is null or the link itself is NULL. if the object inside the element was null, that is a different story, which is how a java null works. The element is there, but the object it contains is null.

Comment: @Humdinger Isn't the element in a linked list defined as the object contained at that index, not the link itself? I've never heard of a *node* in a linked list referred to as an element. If the element is "the link itself", what is an element in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: As far as putting the elements into a set. In order to do so, you would have to iterate through the list two times. Once while going through the list to add it to the set, second to put them back into the list. It would be better just to remove it on first pass.

Comment: @user3580294 It should be good to note that an `ArrayList` is NOT a linked List.

Comment: @Humdinger Yes, I think that is pretty obvious. That wasn't my point at all. Why use inconsistent terminology between the two? And not to mention the `List` interface makes it pretty clear that an element is one of what's *contained*. Even the mathematical definition of an `element` points towards it being one of the things contained *in* the list. Why would it make sense to define an element as a node in a linked list?

Comment: @user3580294 Ok i'll admit my understanding of node and element wasn't correct. I didn't think that one through very well. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have an iterator pointing to the middle of the list, multithreading is not going to help<sup>*</sup> . A simple iteration with a `ListIterator<T>` should do the trick:

```
ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next() == null) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

<sup>*</sup> That is before we take into consideration that the linked list is not thread-safe without external synchronization.

Comment: Also note LinkedList itself is not safe for synchronization, you'd need to externally synchronize it. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#

Comment: @user1071777 Well noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`while(list.remove(null));` would work but might be slow on large list

Edit: In java 8 you can do `list.parallelStream().filter((e)->e!=null)` if you need the result as a linked list again you can do `new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(stream.toArray));`

Comment: That would be slower than iterating. Iterating would at most look at n elements, while your solution can go through more elements. Look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: See [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_Algorithm#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by fastest? The least number of operations is probably just going through one-by-one. If you use multithreading you would likely have to either chop up the list and put it back together or get the indexes and then go through the list in reverse and remove each one manually.

Comment: Just a note, neither chopping up the list and putting it back together nor index-based operations are efficient on linked lists, so your multithreading examples wouldn't really work.

Comment: 2 threads-- one at each end would do. chopping it up still takes iteration, doesn't help a thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty fast way. Worst case though it will be slower than just traversing once. In most cases it will be faster though

```
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.sort(a);
    for(int i=a.size()-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
        if(a.get(i)==null)
            a.remove(i);
        else
            break;
    }
```